# Unable to generate certificate in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, ssl, certificate

I have a problem with Internet Explorer, I'm unable to generate a new certificate from a root one, every time I try to generate  get a prompt which says.

“Error in InstallResponse. Error Number 800B0109 occurred.CertEnroll::InstallResponse: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.  0x800b0109 (-2146762487)”

[image]

Internet explorer is 10, which is the correct for the website i'm trying to work with.

Security levels for ActiveX are the corrects Pop-ups are enabled. And compatibility view is disabled.

Trusted sites are added.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if its handy, but what's the root cert it is using?

Comment: I'm using the root cert facilitated by the company, i just installed it.

Comment: Really? You're still using Internet Explorer? Microsoft's killed it (RIP, man) for good.